# CSV to normalised database MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have been given a CSV with some 1000 contacts - and about 22 fields!

I have normalised all the fields within the database in preparation and have created a temporary table called 'flat_data'

My questions is are their any techniques for quickly turning 'flat data' into normalised data.

At the moment I am:-

- Selecting the columns for a particular table (say addresses) in 'flat_data'

  Inserting those values into the 'addresses' table.

  Then selecting another column ('company name') and doing the same but into the 'companies' table.

Now comes the hard part - the relationship.

What I ended up doing was a few for loops

- Get list of companies

  For each company get the address from 'flat data'

  Then for the address returned look-up the id in the 'addresses' table.

  Then enter the id where company name in 'companies' == company name in 'flat data'

This seems pretty dumb so I was wondering if there was a technique or methodology to do this more efficiently.

Thanks in advance.

This application is in PHP but I can also read C# and VB well enough if people want to weigh in with any code examples (but I am only expecting a methodology / pseudo-code)!!

Answer (score 0):

You may use an ETL like talend in order to pupulate you database. 
http://talend.com/products/data-integration